# Cstring in Postgres ltree query

Tags: postgresql

we use the sql in Postgres using ltree to process some hierarchical data.

However it comes that when we use cast syntax then the query will be very slow and the query plan shows that it actually fist cast to `cstring` and then `lquery`.

```
explain analyse SELECT DISTINCT
                subltree(metric, 0, 6) metric,
                FROM demo
                WHERE
                    metric ~ ('s.a.b' || '.*')::lquery;
```

Query plan:

```
Unique  (cost=144235.79..144273.81 rows=3802 width=100) (actual time=11822.107..11822.107 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=144235.79..144245.29 rows=3802 width=100) (actual time=11822.107..11822.107 rows=1 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (subltree(metric, 0, 6))
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Seq Scan on demo  (cost=0.00..144009.71 rows=3802 width=100) (actual time=1940.149..11822.093 rows=1 loops=1)
               Filter: (metric ~ ('s.a.b.*'::cstring)::lquery)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 3714258
 Total runtime: 11822.139 ms
```

However, when we use sql below, then everything seems to be fine:

```
explain analyse SELECT DISTINCT
                subltree(metric, 0, 6) metric,
                FROM demo
                WHERE
                    metric_name ~ (select ('s.a.b' || '.*')::lquery);
```

Query Plan:

```
Unique  (cost=13294.81..13313.85 rows=3809 width=76) (actual time=0.122..0.126 rows=6 loops=1)
InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
 ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=1)
->  Sort  (cost=13294.79..13304.32 rows=3809 width=76) (actual time=0.121..0.122 rows=6 loops=1)
     Sort Key: metric
     Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on demo  (cost=589.93..13068.25 rows=3809 width=76) (actual time=0.103..0.109 rows=6 loops=1)
           Recheck Cond: (metric ~ $0)
           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on metric_gist_idx  (cost=0.00..588.98 rows=3809 width=0) (actual time=0.097..0.097 rows=6 loops=1)
                 Index Cond: (metric ~ $0)
Total runtime: 0.153 ms
```

Comment: The `cstring` cast looks pretty harmless. What's the plan in the second case?

Comment: @NickBarnes, i updated the query plan for the second case in which the gist index for ltree can be used. and thus can be accomplished very quickly.

Comment: I imagine the `cstring` cast is still there (inside "InitPlan 1"), it's just not in the `EXPLAIN` output. The first plan references a different table (`tb_metric_map` instead of `demo`)... Is this relevant?

Comment: sorry for my typos, i have clear the question again :). I don't know why when `::cstring` is present in the query plan, then the query plan is quite slow and apparently it do not use the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, this is a bug in the `ltree` extension.

The core of the problem is that the I/O routines - the functions responsible for converting between `lquery` and strings - have been incorrectly marked as [`VOLATILE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/xfunc-volatility.html). Because such functions may have side-effects, Postgres can't optimise away any comparisons by using an index; in order to guarantee predictable behaviour, the planner needs to make sure that the cast is called on every row.

It's a different story with subqueries. Where possible, Postgres will only evaluate a subquery once, regardless of volatility. For example, compare the output of

```
SELECT random()
FROM generate_series(1,10);
```

with

```
SELECT (SELECT random())
FROM generate_series(1,10);
```

Anyway, the bug has [already been fixed](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CACfv+pL2oX08SSZSoaHpyC=UbfTFmPt4UmVEKJTH7y=2QMRCBw@mail.gmail.com) in all supported versions of Postgres, but the fix won't affect existing databases. A dump/restore should update the extension. Alternatively, this should have the same effect:

```
ALTER FUNCTION ltree_in(cstring) IMMUTABLE;
ALTER FUNCTION ltree_out(ltree) IMMUTABLE;
ALTER FUNCTION lquery_in(cstring) IMMUTABLE;
ALTER FUNCTION lquery_out(lquery) IMMUTABLE;
ALTER FUNCTION ltxtq_in(cstring) IMMUTABLE;
ALTER FUNCTION ltxtq_out(ltxtquery) IMMUTABLE;
ALTER FUNCTION ltree_gist_in(cstring) IMMUTABLE;
ALTER FUNCTION ltree_gist_out(ltree_gist) IMMUTABLE;
```

Comment: thanks for your continue answers. I get your position. So, if i still use the subquery to convert `text` to `lquery`, it will be legal and correct. Or, i can adopt your suggested way to user the alter function. Am i right?

Comment: @andy: Yes, that's right. It also seems to work if your `lquery` string is a literal, i.e. `'s.a.b.*'::lquery` instead of `('s.a.b' || '.*')::lquery`.